# assigning members of a pair to variables

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is it possible to assign the members of a pair without creating a temporary object?

```
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

pair< bool, int > foo()
{
    return make_pair( false, 3 );
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    bool y;

    auto z = foo();
    x = z.second;
    y = z.first;

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the object `auto z` is needed to "hold" the pair before dissecting it, but its creation might be expensive in the actual code.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes; [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) was invented for this:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

std::pair<bool, int> foo()
{
    return std::make_pair(false, 3);
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    bool y;

    std::tie(y, x) = foo();
    std::cout << x << ',' << y << '\n';
}

// Output: 3,0
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ae333e570344799))

Of course you are still going to have a temporary object *somewhere* (modulo constant optimisations), but this is the most direct you can write the code unless you initialise `x` and `y` directly from their eventual values rather than first creating a pair inside `foo()`.

Comment: @jxh You are returning a temporary by value, the compiler will already perform RVO. What Lightness is referring to (which they are correct about) is that within `std::tie`, they must instantiate the `std::pair` to be able to pull out the `first` and `second` to assign to your variables. `std::tie` is simply a convenience function in that regard.

Comment: @CoryKramer: RVO should mean `tie`'s constructor can avoid the copy too. The only "copy" should be the one created by `make_pair`.

Comment: Theoretically, at least in this contrived case, I'd expect the entire program to just become a few instructions to stream `3` and `0` to _stdout_. It can _all_ be optimised away. If your pair is more complex then you have RVO and move semantics to rely on. Don't worry.

Answer (score 11):

The C++17 already let you to use the Structured binding declaration syntax:

```
#include <iostream>

std::pair<bool, int> foo() {
    return std::make_pair(false, 3);
}

int main() {
    auto [y, x] = foo();               //Structured binding attribution
    std::cout << x << ',' << y << '\n';
}
```

Comment: The official name for this gizmo is a [structured binding declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Comment: It seems that `bool y; int x; [y,x] = foo();` does not work. Variables must not already defined?

Comment: @Chameleon fool() is a function that return a pair of variables (one bool and one int). Here it is the definition of them. When you write auto[y, x] = foo() the compiler knows that y is a bool and x is a int because that is exactly what foo() returns.

Comment: @TheArquitect I understand that, but if `x` & `y` must be already defined (defined before, assigned inside `if` or `switch`), does not work. In this case `std::tie` does the job.

Comment: @Chameleon Basically the differences is tie create the values temporarily and you attribute it (or not) to an existent variable. This new format auto[x, y] just create the variables directly. See this interesting question I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241335/structured-binding-to-replace-stdtie-abuse

Answer (score 3):

I agree wtih The Architect. However, if you are using C++17, then you can also drop the *make_pair* in favor of a more readable *structured binding* in the return statement.

```
#include <iostream>

std::pair<bool, int> foo() {
    return {false, 3}; // <- structured binding
}

int main() {
    auto [y, x] = foo();               // structured binding attribution
    std::cout << x << ',' << y << '\n';
}
```