# Is there a way to easily handle functions returning std::pairs?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, std-pair, minmax

C++11 has function `std::minmax_element` which returns a pair of values. This, however, is quite confusing to handle and read, and produces an extra, later useless variable to pollute the scope.

```
auto lhsMinmax = std::minmax_element(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
int &lhsMin = *(lhsMinMax.first);
int &lhsMax = *(lhsMinmax.second);
```

Is there a better way to do this? Something like:

```
int lhsMin;
int lhsMax;
std::make_pair<int&, int&>(lhsMin, lhsMax).swap(
    std::minmax_element(lhs.begin(), lhs.end()));
```

Comment: no one's mentioned c++17 yet?  https://skebanga.github.io/structured-bindings/

Comment: One question: Is there any efficiency advantage in using `minmax_element` over `min_element` and `max_element` together?

Comment: @xaxxon: C++17 features are not in C++11. The question is tagged C++11. So it's an interesting tangent, but not an actual solution.

Comment: For separate discussion : I raised the above ques here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283673/is-there-any-efficiency-advantage-in-using-minmax-element-over-min-element-and-m

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hence not a real answer.

Comment: @SauravSahu I guess so, but I don't know the underlying algorithm. But otherwise this function would be useless... But it's an often used practice to couple values that are easier to calculate together. I now its easier to calculate cos and sin together.

Comment: @xaxxon: Just saying!

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Given that it's a standard **template** library, you automatically have the source for all algorithms. Mine is in `/usr/include/c++/6.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h`. `minmax_element` only iterates over the range once in there, so yes, it's more effective than separate executions of `min_element` and `max_element` in GCC's implementation.

Comment: I'd argue that your "better...something like" code is not better simply by virtue of being longer, having more elements, and also by needlessly separating definition and initialization.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like enough of a common case to prompt a helper function:

```
template <class T, std::size_t...Idx>
auto deref_impl(T &&tuple, std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
    return std::tuple<decltype(*std::get<Idx>(std::forward<T>(tuple)))...>(*std::get<Idx>(std::forward<T>(tuple))...);
}

template <class T>
auto deref(T &&tuple)
    -> decltype(deref_impl(std::forward<T>(tuple), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value>{})) {
    return deref_impl(std::forward<T>(tuple), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value>{});
}

// ...

int lhsMin;
int lhsMax;
std::tie(lhsMin,lhsMax) = deref(std::minmax_element(lhs.begin(), lhs.end()));
```

`index_sequence` is C++14, but a full implementation [can be made in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611/3233393).

Note: I'd keep the repeated `decltype` in `deref`'s return type even in C++14, so that SFINAE can apply.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f58f889d68415aa2)

Comment: Would SFINAE not apply anyway?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I re-checked just to be sure and can confirm: since nothing restricts `T` in the function's signature, I get a hard error when instantiating the function's body. See [this quickly hacked test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/390744d8f0deac2e).

Comment: Hmm, guess SFINAE doesn't work how I thought it did :(

Comment: I dont understand, doens't std::tie bind straight to a pair?

Comment: @ViktorSehr what do you mean ? `std::tie` returns a `std::tuple<T&>`. However, all `std::tuple` metafunctions, such as `std::tuple_size`, work with `std::pair` too.

Comment: The example on cppreference demonstrates that it works with `std::pair` out of the box http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie

Comment: @StoryTeller it does, but the types of the variables must match the types of the elements of the pair. The problem here is that OP wants the values that the iterators refer to, not the iterators themselves. You can use `std::tie` and bind to the pair, but the pair contains the wrong values.

Comment: If anything I'd want to wrap `std::minmax_element`, into a function that returned an `optional< pair<int, int> >`

Comment: `std::tuple_size` will fail for lvalue tuples, if you happen to care about those. It needs `std::remove_reference[_t]`. This also has the same issue as the other `deref` answer, in that prvalue-yielding iterators will cause dangling references through `std::forward_as_tuple`.

Comment: @Xeo well-spotted. This should be fixed AFAICT.

Answer (score 32):

With *structured binding* from C++17, you may directly do

```
auto [lhsMinIt, lhsMaxIt] = std::minmax_element(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
```

Comment: Neat! Can you get the value pair out of the iterator pair in one line also?

Comment: @AdamHunyadi: C++1z is the "it doesn't formally exist yet" name for C++17, like how C++0x became C++11 (late!) and C++1y because C++14.

Comment: Upvoted because it's an interesting discussion point, and _will_ be a good solution, but this actually doesn't answer the question (which is about C++11).

Comment: @rubenvb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241335/structured-binding-to-replace-stdtie-abuse/40241520#40241520

Comment: @rubenvb I think it boils down to terser syntax, the ability to declare and assign the variables in one statement, plus the ability to infer the variable types.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What will be the standard after `C++1z`? `C++2{`? :-)

Comment: @celtschk: Heh, I actually tried to figure that out after writing my last comment. Inconclusive. I suspect C++2ẋ, but that's just me.

Comment: BTW, as of now, this syntax is not supported by clang 3.9 or gcc7snapshot ([on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/Y4HX4P), where I put a function that uses `std::minmax_element` on a `vector<int>` so it's easy to look at the asm output.  re: [discussion on branch prediction vs. branchless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283673/is-there-any-efficiency-advantage-in-using-minmax-element-over-min-element-and-m#comment67860602_40284138). )

Answer (score 23):

To avoid polluting your scope, you could enclose the assignment in a smaller scope:

```
int lhsMin, lhsMax;

{
    auto it = std::minmax_element(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
    lhsMin = *it.first;
    lhsMax = *it.second;
}
```

alternatively, you can use a lambda

```
int lhsMin, lhsMax;

std::tie(lhsMin, lhsMax) = [&]{
    auto it = std::minmax_element(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
    return std::make_tuple(*it.first, *it.second);
}();
```

Comment: It should be noted that neither will work for assigning references as in the first part of the OP. (The second part is mangled so it's hard to say but it also hints at assigning two `int&`s.)

Comment: With the enclosing scope and `std::tie` is easier to read than a lambda I think.

Comment: Why the semicolon at the end of the first example?

Answer (score 4):

I'd just be more direct and write my own version of `minmax_element`:

```
template <class Iter, class R = typename iterator_traits<Iter>::reference>
std::pair<R,R> deref_minmax(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    auto iters = std::minmax_element(first, last);
    return std::pair<R,R>{*iters.first, *iters.second};
}
```

Which is then just:

```
int lo, hi;
std::tie(lo, hi) = deref_minmax(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
```

This would limit you to just a single copy of the elements (which isn't that much of a big deal with `int`s), also let you maintain access to the references into the actual container.

---

In C++17, for fun, we could write a generalized dereferencer:

```
template <class Tuple>
auto deref(Tuple&& tup) {
    return std::apply([](auto... args) {
        return std::tuple <decltype(*args)...>(*args...);
    }, tup);
}

auto& [lo, hi] = deref(std::minmax_element(lhs.begin(), lhs.end()));
```

Here `lo` and `hi` are references into the container itself.

Comment: Your `deref` function can result in undefined behaviour. If the iterators (or whatever `args` ends up being) return prvalues, you get dangling references, since `std::forward_as_tuple` returns an rvalue reference for them.

Comment: @Xeo That's up to the caller to not keep references then.

Comment: Wrong. You get dangling references at the `return std::forward_as_tuple(...);` point, since the temporaries are created in that scope and are dead as soon as the function returns.

Comment: @Xeo Ah, misunderstood your comment initially. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of assigning two *references* at once in the current revision of the standard, if that's what you are after. Note that none of the other answers do that, except Barry's which requires C++17 and a helper template.

However, if you want a read-write access to your minimal and maximal elements, why not just go with the iterators the `minmax_element` provides you directly? It's likely to generate identical machine code as using references anyway, at least if your `lhs` is a `ContiguousContainer` but maybe in other cases as well.

You will need to rely a bit less on the automatic type deduction, for example,

```
decltype(lhs.begin()) lhsMinIt, lhsMaxIt;
std::tie(lhsMinIt, lhsMaxIt) = std::minmax_element(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
/* now access your minimum and maximum as *lhsMinIt and *lhsMaxIt */
```

If you know the type of `lhs` will be one of the standard containers, you can use a bit cleaner type designation `decltype(lhs)::iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++14 or greater

```
template<class=void, std::size_t...Is>
auto indexer( std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
  return [](auto&&f){
    return f( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto indexer() {
  return indexer( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
template<class F>
auto fmap_over_tuple( F&& f ) {
  return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&& tuple) {
    using Tuple = decltype(tuple);
    using Tuple_d = std::decay_t<Tuple>;
    auto index = indexer< std::tuple_size< Tuple_d >::value >();
    return index(
      [&f, &tuple](auto&&...Is) {
        using std::get;
        return std::make_tuple(
          f( get<Is>( std::forward<Tuple>(tuple) ) )...
        );
      }
    );
  };
}
```

so `fmap_over_tuple` takes a function object.  It returns a function object that, when passed a tuple-like, proceeds to call the function object on each element of the tuple-like, and generate a tuple from it.

We then write dereference tuple:

```
auto dereference_tuple = fmap_over_tuple(
  [](auto&& e) { return *e; }
);
```

Now in C++17 we do:

```
auto[Min, Max] = dereference_tuple( std::minmax_element(lhs.begin(), lhs.end() );
```

and bob is your uncle.

In C++11, just do what you did.  Clean enough.

[C++14 live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/365b1eaddaf28519).