# Use auto for only one variable with structured binding

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to update a variable passed to a function with a structured binding:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

std::pair<int, double> func(double y)
{
    return {1, 1.3+y};
}

int main() {
    double y = 1.0;
    auto [x, y2] = func(y);
    y = y2;
    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to avoid the extra assignment `y = y2` and using something like

```
[auto x, y] = func(y); // this does not work
```

or

```
std::tie(auto x, y) = func(y); // this does not work
```

Comment: I will ask the obvious just in case: you can't simply move the declaration of `y` to the structured binding?

Comment: I think the idea is that `y` should be already declared because it's being used as an argument to `func`. In this code snippet, it could be replaced with `auto [x, y] = func(1.0)`, yes.

Comment: It looks like people tried to come up with something hybridizing structured bindings and `std::tie` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590449/c17-structured-binding-that-also-includes-an-existing-variable). Not sure if either of those solutions will be very useful for you.

Comment: In `auto [x, y] = foo()`, `auto` doesn't apply to each individual identifier. Instead it applies to a single invisible variable that's initialized with the return value of `foo()`. Identifiers declared in brackets become (loosely speaking) magical aliases for the members of this hidden variable. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question narrowly:

No, you can't reuse an existing variable in a structured binding. Structured binding always declares new variables.

That being said, there are other options - like `std::tie`, as @Robert A has demonstrated.

Answer (score 2):

A third option:

```
decltype(func(y).first) x;
std::tie(x, y) = func(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

A structured binding is a *declaration*; it cannot be used e.g. for assignment into an already declared variable.

If you are allowed to move the declaration of `y` and you ever only need it to make a function call, you could abuse the scope of the the capture list of an immediately invoked lambda, and let it shadow (only within the scope of the lambda) the variable `y` that is declared as part of a structured binding, which is in turn initialized using the return from the immediately invoked lambda:

```
auto [x, y] = [y = 1.0](){ return func(y); }();
            // ^^^^^^^ actually not at all in namespace scope,
            //         but a data member of the closure type
            //         of the lambda expression.
```

You could likewise use a named lambda:

```
const auto l = [y = 1.0](){ return func(y); };
auto [x, y] = l();
```

As is typically the case with shadowing alongside the somewhat complex scoping rules of C++, this is likely only to confuse readers, though.