# Is there something that limits the future C++ standard from introducing multiple return values?

Tags: c++, standards, multiple-return-values

In newer versions of the C++ standard, we are allowed to write functions that have multiple return values such as

```
std::tuple<int, std::string, float> someFunction0();
```

This forces us to call the functions as

```
int a;
std::string last_name;
float f_par;
std::tie(a, last_name, f_par) = someFunction0();
```

My question is, is there something that prevents the C++ committee from introducing a "simpler" form of multiple return value syntax? Such as

```
[int, std::string, float] someFunction1();
```

which would allow you to declare more inline when calling the function

```
[int a, std::string last_name, float f_par] = someFunction1();
```

(There are probably better syntactic solutions than the one that I provided.)

Compiler-wise, it shouldn't be an issue, right?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think what you are asking about [already exists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Structured binding to replace std::tie abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241335/structured-binding-to-replace-stdtie-abuse).

Comment: Ah, rats, seems like I haven't done my homework! Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Rare is the circumstance where you need a function to return multiple values, but that the collection of those values is not sufficiently meaningful in and of itself to be worthy of having a named struct type. And even if the group of return values is inherently meaningless, using a struct means that you can at least give the return values *names*, which makes it clear on the receiving end what the values *mean*. Think of how terrible `map::insert` code is because of the inscrutable meaning of `pair.second`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example `std::tuple<int, std::string, float> someFunction0();` still returns **one** `tuple` object, comprised of multiple sub-objects.

> is there something that prevents the C++ committee from introducing a "simpler" form of multiple return value syntax?

You can use C++17 [structured binding declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to unpack/destructure it:

> **Case 2: binding a tuple-like type**
>
> ```
> float x{};
> char  y{};
> int   z{};
>
> std::tuple<float&,char&&,int> tpl(x,std::move(y),z);
> const auto& [a,b,c] = tpl;
> // a names a structured binding that refers to x; decltype(a) is float&
> // b names a structured binding that refers to y; decltype(b) is char&&
> // c names a structured binding that refers to the 3rd element of tpl; decltype(c) is co`
> ```